# Basic Measure Theory: Equivalent Condition for showing a measurable set has measure 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I know this is basic...but perhaps I have been staring at this for too long now... I want to show that:

If $\mu$ is a measure on $(X,A)$ and $f:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $A$-measurable function then

\begin{equation}
\mu(f>0) = 0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \mu(f>\epsilon) = 0 \quad \forall \epsilon >0
\end{equation}

And similarly:
\begin{equation}
\mu(f<0) = 0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \mu(f<-\epsilon) = 0 \quad \forall \epsilon >0
\end{equation}

Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: $\{x\mid f(x)>0\}=\bigcup_n \{x\mid f(x)>1/n\}$

Comment: To echo Michael: $(0,\infty) = \cup_n ({1 \over n},\infty)$.

Comment: Let $B=\{x:f(x)>\epsilon\}$ and $ C=\{x: f(x)>0\}. $ Then $B, C,$ and $C\setminus B$ are $\mu$-measurable sets   because $f$ is a $\mu$-measurable function. And $B, \;C\setminus B$ are disjoint. So  $0=\mu (C)=\mu  (B\cup (C\setminus B))=\mu (B)+\mu (C\setminus B).$

Comment: Woops I didn't see these comments earlier! Thank you so much for the help and these hints - I think I got it now =)